# why I can't insert into database successfully

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want to insert a tuple of data into mysql.

I did

```
INSERT INTO goods_table (name,kind,price,discount, store ,detail）
            VALUES("abc","A",3960,10,100,'adf');
```

**the definition of table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `goods_table` (
  `id` int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have checked the mysql mannual for insert statement

> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

I don't know why mysql always report the same error many many times!

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
         that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
        '("abc","A",3960,10,100,'adf')' at line 1
```

this is a very simple operation.. I have checked very character of my statement to official example. and I have been stuck at this simple statement for a whole afternoon, which is unbelievable.

**update:**
I try to change the way of quotes

```
insert into `goods_table` (`name`,`kind`,`price`,`discount`,`store`）
values ('abc','A',3960,10,100);
```

it make no changes to the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '）
values ('abc','A',3960,10,100)' at line 1
```

many people say this is caused by using double quotes, but it is exactly not.
I follow the answer and execute

```
INSERT INTO goods_table (name,kind,price,discount, store ,detail)VALUES("abc","A",3960,10,100,"adf");
```

I use double quotes, it did

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, i.e. `"abc","A",3960,...` should be `'abc','A',3960,...`

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/335858) for details on using different kinds of quotes.

Comment: @ juergen .. I don't know how to use trigger, create a table and insert into it is all I have done

Comment: What error message do you get after changing the query. The same?

Comment: @ juergen ,  I find out I paste the error code of different time, because I have tried to modify the statement many times, and it reported many times error. I paste the error of different time..

Comment: It actually does change the error. Don't you see the difference? It is now before  `values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
）
```

which is a special character.

Use this instead:

```
)
```

Complete query:

```
insert into `goods_table` (`name`,`kind`,`price`,`discount`,`store`) values ('abc','A',3960,10,100);
                                                                   ^------ here
```

Comment: OMG! I have wasted a whole afternoon to solve the bug caused by a small character! I even doubt I install a fake mysql

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO tableName( name, kind, price, discount, store, detail`) VALUES ('abc','A',3960,10,100,'adf');

## use '' sinqle quotes for varchar values do not include primary key if it auto generated